# Function Finding using pictures

Tags: c#, math, image-processing

Is it possible to take a picture of a line and analyze the black line versus the white background and create a best fit function of the line using image analysis? If so, what would be the right direction to start looking?

Comment: Best fit over what?  Usually a best fit is performed over a series of points.

Comment: exactly... I was thinking that by analyzing the x and y coordinates of the black pixels on the image I could create a mathmatical representation of the line

Comment: Does [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396334/are-there-any-c-sharp-math-libraries-that-do-interpolation-extrapolation) help?

Comment: Is it a straight line or curved?  Do you want to follow the curve or find the best fit straight line to the curve?

Comment: its a curve, and I already figured this out, but thankyou for your help. I am just using the raw data points that I am gathering from the chart. It is a good enough density to approximate any value I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, from your comments, it seems that you need only get a list of points which represent the black line.  That is simple enough, so this example simply grabs black pixels and saves their {x,y} coordinates.  If you need something more complex you can add it on top of this.

```
using System.Drawing;

...

List<Point> GetBlackPixels( Bitmap bmp )
{
    var points = new List<Point>();
    for( int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; ++y )
    {
        for( int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; ++x )
        {
            if( bmp.GetPixel( x, y ) == Color.Black )
            {
                points.Add( new Point( x, y );
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Note that `GetPixel` is relatively slow.  That doesn't mean it is not suitable for *your use case*, it just means that, on large images, you may need something faster.  If so, call [LockBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d.aspx) on the `Bitmap` and get a pointer directly to memory.

Remember though, use the easier version (what I posted) first before going that route. GDI+ may be just fine for you.

And again, this code simply meets your stated requirements.  It will only save points that are true black.  You may or may not need to add more code if you have a more complex scenario that you did not describe in your question.

Comment: wow this is excactly what I was doing while waiting for an answer on here! thanks a bunch it really helps to know I am on the right track. I guess once I get the x and y locations of the black pixels I will have to use some calculus to create a best fit line / moving average line. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Run a [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) over the points that are considered to be black (i.e. darker than a given threshold value).  This approach is tolerant of image compression artifacts.