# function interpolation c#

Tags: c#, .net, math, interpolation

I know there have been several questions asked relating to interpolation, but I have not found any answers that would be helpful enough for me so I have the following question.

I have two arrays of points. One tracks time (x axis) and one tracks expenses (y axis) and 
I want to get something like this:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 10}, {1, 122}, {2, 3.65}, {3, 56.3}, {4, 12.4}, {5, 0}}, x]
```

(In Mathematica that returs a constructed polynomial that fits the points). Is it possible, to return a `func<double,double>` constructed from two `double` arrays in C#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2414935/922198 if this helps!

Comment: I checked that already but it does not seem to solve my problem completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution myself after a long day of search. I interpolate a function using Lagrange Interpolation. 
A `Func<double,double>` can be then easily constructed using DLINQ. 
e.g

```
public Func<doube,double> GetFunction()
{
    LagrangeInterpolation lagInter = new LagrangeInterpolation(xVals, yVals);
    return ( val => lagInter(GetValue(val) );
}
```

This returns the `Func<double,double>` object. (I know that creating a new object each time is not a good solution but this is just for demonstrational purposes)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www2.math.umd.edu/~dlevy/classes/amsc466/lecture-notes/interpolation-chap.pdf) paper describes exactly what you want. The [Vandermonde Determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) method is quite simple to implement as it requires to compute the determinant of a matrix in order to obtain the coefficients of the interpolating polynomial.
I'd suggest to build a class with an appropriate interface though, as building `Func`s on the fly is pretty complicated (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315819/expression-lambda-and-query-generation-at-runtime-simplest-where-example) for an example). You could do something like:

```
public class CosineInterpolation {
    public CosineInterpolation(double[] x, double[] y) { ... }
    public double Interpolate(double x) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Well this only describes the process of interpolation which I am familliar with. My question is of more programming nature, getting the func object out of the whole thing. Thanks, anyways, seems very iterestng paper though. +1 on a great paper though.

Comment: @Andrej building Funcs seem to be quite messy to me, I'd use a more "conventional" approach