# polynomial extrapolation using C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, extrapolation

Can anyone help me to find a efficiency method for polynomial extrapolation using C#?

Example: I have 10 different coordinates(XY plane) and need to find 11th point according to this 10 points using a very efficiency algorithm.

please suggest me if there is any other method except extrapolation.

Thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any C# math libraries that do interpolation / extrapolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396334/are-there-any-c-sharp-math-libraries-that-do-interpolation-extrapolation)

Comment: what is the real N (point count) ? accuracy ? runtime limit ? (I assume points are 2D in cartesian orthonormal system if not then specify) what have you tried so far ?